# Sending message through installed applications

Tags: android

I would like to share a url from my android application. I would like to share this url through the installed applications in my device(bluetooth, facebook, google mail, messaging etc.).

Given below is the code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class SendURL extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Button button;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent picMessageIntent = new Intent(
                android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                picMessageIntent.setType("plain/text");

                /**
                 * //Code for sending image
                 * picMessageIntent.setType("image/jpeg"); File downloadedPic =
                 * new
                 * File("/sdcard/download/"+"1287567819_Einstein_1_JPEG.jpg");
                 * picMessageIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                 * Uri.fromFile(downloadedPic));
                 */

                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(picMessageIntent,
                        "Send your url using:"));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When I press a button called share, the installed applications in the phone which can share this url, should be listed like [this](http://www.4shared.com/photo/8jlZgwNB/share.html). The user can select an application from this list and share the url through the chosen application(gmail, facebook, messaging etc.).
With the given code, I get only gmail and bluetooth. I do not get facebook, messaging etc. Please advise, in order that I can send the url through all the applications in the phone which are capable of doing this.

Any help in this regard is appreciated.
Looking forward,
Regards

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a subject and some text - at the moment you're not sharing a url, just creating a blank message.

Try something like this:

```
Intent picMessageIntent = new Intent(
android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
picMessageIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "my url subject");
picMessageIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Go to url: "+"http://google.com/");
picMessageIntent.setType("plain/text");

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(picMessageIntent, "Send your url using:"));
```

Replace `"my url subject"` and `"Go to url " +"http://google.com/"` with the subject and url you wish to share.

Comment: Ok..thx alot..i will check the way you told..i reconfirm once again..i need to send it through the installed and default applications in the phone(facebook, messaging etc.)

Comment: Try adding a subject and some text - at the moment you're not sharing a url, just creating a blank message.                                                                                                                               I tried this, but still facebook and messaging is not shown in chooser as seen here -http://www.4shared.com/photo/8jlZgwNB/share.html  . Please advise.

Comment: Any android experts who know about this, please help.

Comment: I do not know why I do not get ample support from this forum. This is not my first experience here. I am quite sure the queries which I ask here are technically doable stuffs. What I seek is just some expert supports.After plenty of google search only, I seek for expert support here. StackOverflow, kindly live up to our expectations...